# Project vue + vite + quasar inconsistent after build, taking long time to load some fonts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a project in Vue3 + Quasar + Vite, I've been developing it and so far so good. But when I did the build and uploaded it to the production environment it has some inconsistencies, usually the first time I access the page in the day, the page loads without some quasar fonts, icons and with a horizontal scroll, after refreshing the page it back to normal operation, the problem is that this behavior keeps repeating itself, print below the operation when it occurs correctly (circled in orange) and when the error occurs (circled in red), just a font that I believe is generated by Quasar, it's taking 158798ms to load. Someone had this issue before?

Error

[image: 1]